# Подскажите как сделать, такую 3d анимацию для при движении мыши

Tags: javascript, jquery, анимация

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Тут на главной сайта http://dgpacker.ru/, есть изображения, которые создают эффект 3-d при движении мышкой по оси-x
оно так же изменяет свой внешний вид, подгружая, как я понял нужное фото (скрины ниже),
подскажите пожалуйста, как можно реализовать такое-же, что мне для этого вообще потребуется, придется ли создавать так же много фотографий 3d-обекта или тут просто используется какая-та библиотека со своими изображениями, всем спасибо за внимание

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А тут на главной это где?

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 спасибо, указал ссылку

Comment: "Жесть" какая-то. По 100 PNG картинок на каждую анимацию. А то, что они квадратами идут по началу, так это прогрузка.

Comment: @UModeL да, прогружается оно конечно интересно)

Comment: @Houckz: такой подход к анимации, я видел в LazerBasic на ZX-spectrum, году так в 1994 ;-) Спрайты...

Comment: https://www.ajax-zoom.com/examples/example32.php

Comment: А как тебе такое, @UModeL https://lakhta.center/ru/about/objects/