# Как заменить 3D модель по клику?

Tags: three.js

Не получается изменить 3D модель по клику на кнопку в реальном времени.
Изначально грузится дефолтная модель из массива.

Для этого сделал переменную `var counter = 0;` он отвечает за номер модели в массиве.

После написал функцию которая перезаписывает её значение. Предварительно пред загрузил все модельки при загрузке страницы. Подскажите, как можно заменить(перерисовать) модель в realtime без перезагрузки страницы? Т.е, нужно по клику на кнопку менять объект на другой

```js
import * as THREE from './three.module.js';
import { OBJLoader} from './OBJLoader.js';
import { OrbitControls } from './OrbitControls.js';

var container;
var camera, scene, renderer, controls;
var object;


// Object info
const pack_box = {
  id: "pack_box",
  model: ["pack_box", "15x15", "25x25", "35x35", "40x40"],
  minDistance: "13",
  perCam: "45",
  maxDistance: "13",
  posX: "50",
  posY: "65",
  posZ: "-135",
  material: ["white", "grey", "craft"]
};

const pencil_box = {
  id: "pencil_box",
  model: ["pencil_box", "15x15", "25x25", "35x35", "40x40"],
  minDistance: "12",
  perCam: "75",
  maxDistance: "12",
  posX: "45",
  posY: "60",
  posZ: "100",
  material: ["white", "grey", "craft"]
};

const hidden_box = {
  id: "hidden_box",
  model: ["hidden_box", "20x20", "30x30", "40x40", "45x45", "50x50"],
  minDistance: "15",
  perCam: "35",
  maxDistance: "15",
  posX: "50",
  posY: "0.6",
  posZ: "-135",
  material: ["white", "grey", "craft"]
};

const cover_box = {
  id: "cover_box",
  model: ["cover_box", "25x25", "35x35", "45x45", "45x45", "50x50", "60x60" ],
  minDistance: "12",
  perCam: "35",
  maxDistance: "15",
  posX: "50",
  posY: "65",
  posZ: "-135",
  material: ["white", "grey", "craft"]
};

let current_box = [];
let box = document.getElementsByName("size");
// Object URL init
const url = window.location.href;
const splittedUrl = url.split("/");
const id = splittedUrl[splittedUrl.length - 1];

if (id === "") {
  current_box = pack_box;
} else if (id === "#pack_box") {
  current_box = pack_box;
} else if (id === "#pencil_box") {
  current_box = pencil_box;
} else if (id === "#hidden_box") {
  current_box = hidden_box;
} else if (id === "#cover_box") {
  current_box = cover_box;
}


init();
animate();

function init() {


  var basePath = '/models/';
  container = document.querySelector('.figure_3d');

  // camera 
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(current_box.perCam, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.25, 20);
  camera.position.x = current_box.posX;
  camera.position.y = current_box.posY;
  camera.position.z = current_box.posZ;
  camera.rotation.y += 1 * (Math.PI / 180);

  // control camera
  controls = new OrbitControls(camera, container);
  controls.enablePan = false;
  controls.enableZoom = true;
  controls.minDistance = current_box.minDistance;
  controls.maxDistance = current_box.maxDistance;
  controls.update();

  // scene
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xFFFFFF);
  const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x999999);
  scene.add(ambientLight);

  const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.4);
  pointLight.position.set(700, 700, 1000);
  camera.add(pointLight);
  scene.add(camera);

  // Object resize
  function onWindowResize() {
    const maxValue = 550;
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight;
    w = innerWidth < maxValue ? innerWidth : maxValue;
    h = innerWidth < maxValue ? innerWidth : maxValue;
    camera.aspect = w / h;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize(w, h);
    console.log('Object resized: ' + w + 'x' + h);

  }

  function loadModel() {
    setTexture(counter);
  }
  // manager
  var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager(loadModel);

  manager.onProgress = function(item, loaded, total) {

    console.log(item, loaded, total);

  };
  // texture
  var textures = [];

  var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader(manager);
  textures.push(
    textureLoader.load(basePath + 'materials/' + current_box.material[0] + '.jpg'),
    textureLoader.load(basePath + 'materials/' + current_box.material[1] + '.jpg'),
    textureLoader.load(basePath + 'materials/' + current_box.material[2] + '.jpg')
  );
  material_1.addEventListener("click", function() {
    setTexture(0);
  });
  material_2.addEventListener("click", function() {
    setTexture(1);
  });
  material_3.addEventListener("click", function() {
    setTexture(2);
  });

  function setTexture(texIdx) {
    object.traverse(function(child) {

      if (child.isMesh) {
        child.material.map = textures[texIdx];
      }
    });
  }

  //progress load
  function onProgress(xhr) {

    if (xhr.lengthComputable) {

      var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
      console.log('Object ' + Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded');

    }

  }
  //error
  function onError() {}

  // model

  var modelsPackArray = [];
  var modelObj = [];

  // номер дефолтной модели.
  var counter = 0;


  var loader = new OBJLoader(manager);
  current_box.model.forEach((mdl, idx) => {
    loader.load(basePath + mdl + ".obj", obj => {
      modelObj[idx] = obj;
    })
  })

  function loadModels() {
    if (counter > current_box.length) return;
    box.forEach(box => {
      box.addEventListener('click', e => {
        const data_id = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');
        counter = data_id;
        console.log('перезаписываем counter = ' + data_id);
      })
    })
    loader.load(basePath + current_box.model[counter] + '.obj', function(obj) {
      object = obj;
      modelsPackArray.push(obj);
      scene.add(obj);
      loadModel();
    }, onProgress, onError);
  }
  loadModels();

  //render
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  container.append(renderer.domElement);
  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, true);
}


function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();

}

function render() {

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

```html
<input name="size" id="size_1" data-id="1" type="radio">
<label for="size_1">100x100x50 </label>
<br>
<input name="size" id="size_2" data-id="2" type="radio">
<label for="size_2">120х120х70 </label>
<br>
<input name="size" id="size_3" data-id="3" type="radio">
<label for="size_3">140х140х90 </label>
<br>
<input name="size" id="size_4" data-id="4" type="radio">
<label for="size_4">150х150х100 </label>
```

Comment: а почему не поместить все модельки в один THREE.Object3D и дать всем visible = false (когда visible: false, то модельки не рендеряться) и по клику давать visible: true конкретной модели скрывая неактивные? или если менять текстуры, то нужно прочекать faces, правильно ли вообще ложится текстура, или как вариант не те мэши, на которые ложится текстура, могут быть и в группах меши

Comment: @LieutenantJimDangle меня посетила та же мысль )

Comment: Если можно, напишите пожалуйста наглядный пример?

Comment: Или можно ли их как-то подгружать по клику, а не предзагрузкой, в случае если их будет к примеру больше 10 моделек? Может как-то через JSON это всё дело хранить а не хардкодить? К сожалению я только начал изучать Three.js, очень сложно пока вникнуть на примерах, так как там нет подобных примеров с моим случаем....(

Comment: если больше 10, то лучше их загрузить сразу и работать с ними, если же необходимость показать первым экран, юай и эти дела, то можно асинхронно или по клику загружать, но тогда нужно придумать какой-то спинер/лоадер, который будет дожидаться загрузки и добавления на сцену модельки, что как бы не очень. В коде немного хаоса и понять или модельку менять или текстуру? или и то и другое. и какие модельки, если используется travers, и зачем, если у модели есть материал уже? По хорошему нужно смотреть на живой пример с моделями и там править.

Comment: а касательно наглядного примера, const obj = new THREE.Object3D(); и форычем пройтись по всем текущим моделям и obj.add(newModel), где ей дать name и потом при смене обьекта obj.getObjectByName(name).visible = true, остальным children.for... child.visible = false, как-то так:)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1124918/224917 не по клику, а по mouseover, но принцип показа нужной модели тот же )

Comment: Вот вам наглядный пример того что есть http://go-trs.com/constructor/#hidden_box. Вариант с подгрузкой сразу всех моделей не очень подходит, их может быть и больше 20. Код указан в вопросе, всё вроде прокоментировал и всё понятно там. Нужно менять модель в зависимости от выбранной модели. Если откроете консоль и поклацаете на выбор размера, то мою логику вы поймете. Просто что с этим делать дальше, я пока ума не приложу.

Comment: @prisoner849, пожалуйста, если можно применить данный пример что вы указали, с учётом моего кода, как это можно сделать? Честно ума не приложу. Всё на что меня хватило в данном примере, так это сменить mouseover на клик
https://codepen.io/danykrass/pen/mdVdaGR